# Does Parse, MongoDB and AWS have a way to view data?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, parse-platform

I have successfully set up Parse on AWS with a MongoDB for my iOS App.  I was trying to find out if there is a way to view my data once my app saves it to the DB.  I could not find any tools for viewing the data.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the parse dashboard to view your data in the browsers. https://github.com/parse-community/parse-dashboard

There is also an unofficial iOS dashboard app. https://github.com/nathantannar4/Parse-Dashboard-for-iOS

And I am currently working on an unofficial android dashboard. https://github.com/bitterbit/Parse-Dashboard-Android

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I saw the first link, but do I set that up on AWS or on my local machine?

Comment: Whichever you would like. If you want to access the dashboard from any computer, setup the dashboard on aws so it is reachable from anywhere. Both setups will work and you can even do both at the same time.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much, I have lost 2 days fooling with this setup.  I tried to install it on AWS but keep getting a 502 Gateway error.  Any ideas?